# CLI Data Gem using Ruby

Tags: ruby

Newbie question here. I'm working on my first CLI Data Gem project that scrapes live data from 2 websites.

The user can press '1' to see article #1 or '2' to see article #2. 
The user can type 'list' to see both article titles stacked one on top of the other. 
Typing 'exit' should exit the app with "See you tomorrow for more articles."

When the user types literally anything else, the program should say "No Bueno. Type 1, 2, list, or exit"

So far, pressing '1' or '2' works. Typing 'list' works

**The error happens when** I press 'exit'..

It will say 
"No Bueno. Type 1, 2, list, or exit" (my custom error message)
and
"See you tomorrow for more articles."

when it should just say - "See you tomorrow for more articles."

```
 def call
    list_items
    menu
    goodbye
  end

  def list_items
    # here doc - http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html
    puts "Today's Designer News:"
    @articles = DesignerNews::Article.today
    @articles.each.with_index(1) do |article, i|
      puts "#{i}. #{article.title} - #{article.name} - #{article.date} - #{article.url}"
    end
  end

  def menu
    input = nil 
    while input !="exit"
      puts "Enter the number of the item you'd like to read, type list to see the list, or type exit:"
      input = gets.strip.downcase

      if input.to_i > 0 
        the_article = @articles[input.to_i-1]
        puts "#{the_article.title} - #{the_article.name} - #{the_article.date} - #{the_article.url}"
      elsif input == "list"
        list_items
      else
        puts "No Bueno. Type 1, 2, list, or exit"
      end
    end
  end

  def goodbye
    puts "See you tomorrow for more articles."
  end
end
```

any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking for `exit` input inside the loop. Changing the last `else` to this should work:

```
elsif input != "exit"
  puts "No Bueno. Type 1, 2, list, or exit"
end
```